# jquery slidedown slideup browser issue

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menuitem

http://jsfiddle.net/boyee007/dYXxU/
the **SlideDown and SlideUp** working fine in Firefox but not Chrome or Explorer or Opera i guess!
anyone know to sort it out please!

HTML:

```
<ul class="mainnav">
    <li class="aboutus"><a href="#" title="About Us">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <div>
                <li ><a href="#">What is the CU?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">What are the benefits?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reward system explained</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
// NAVIGATION
    $(".mainnav li").hover(function(){
        $("ul", this).slideDown("fast");
    }, function() {
        $("ul", this).slideUp("fast");
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing:
`ul li:hover ul {display:block;}`

Once I removed that css rule the content slide down correctly in chrome on mouseover and back up on mouseout.